# Shopify Multiple Product Options

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I currently have the following form which is all good and generates the multiple variant dropdowns, but when trying to add it to cart using `Cart.js` it doesn't actually add anything to the cart. I'm unsure if I'm missing some code here but what I've done currently in my theme is:

**In my header**

`{{ 'option_selection.js' | shopify_asset_url | script_tag }}`

**Add to cart Form**

```
      <form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="AddToCartForm" class="form-vertical" data-cart-submit>

        <select id="variant-select" name="id">
          {% for variant in product.variants %}
            {% if variant.available %}
              <option value="{{variant.id}}">{{ variant.title }} for {{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}{% if variant.price < variant.compare_at_price %} usually {{ variant.compare_at_price | money_with_currency }}{% endif %}</option>
            {% else %}
        <option value="{{variant.id}}" disabled="disabled">{{ variant.title }} - sold out!</option>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </select>

        <input name="cart-add" type="submit" class="button" id="cart-add" value="Buy Now!">
        <span id="price-field"></span>
      </form>
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is there a call somewhere to initialize the variant selectors? (Example: `new Shopify.OptionSelectors('variant-select', { product: {{ product | liquid }}, onVariantSelected: someFunction })`).

Comment: One way to check to see if your option selectors are doing anything is to inspect the document with your browser's dev tools to un-hide your variant ID select-box (and any hidden wrapping elements that have been injected by the OptionSelector code) to make sure that your ID field is updating properly. If there's no ID, then nothing would be added to the cart, so that might explain your symptoms.

Comment: @DaveB the only code is the above in the question.

Comment: Aha - then you're including the option_selection code but not using any of it :) One sec, will whip up an example as an answer for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the call to initialize the option selectors. That, combined with no default value for your variant drop-down, could be resulting in no valid ID being posted to Shopify when you try the Add-To-Cart.

One thing to do would be to automatically select the appropriate variant in your select-box.  Shopify's product objects have a field called 'selected_or_first_available_variant', which comes in useful here. Example:

```
<option value="{{variant.id}}"  {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %} selected {%endif %}>{{ variant.title }}</option>
```

(I often refer back to Shopify's excellent [reference for Liquid objects](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/product), which can help give you ideas for what's possible)

If you're using Shopify's OptionSelectors, you may also need to make your variant ID field `display:none` - when OptionSelectors runs, it will automatically create 1-3 drop-downs for you based on the product's option dimensions.

For example: a product that comes in 3 different sizes and 2 different colours would have up to 6 different variants.  Your initial select box will have all available combos as "Small / Red", "Small / Blue", "Medium / Red", etc.

Running the OptionSelectors code on the above example product would give you two selectors: one for size, one for colour. Under the hood, the OptionSelectors code takes the values of from each individual option-dimension (eg: "Small" and "Blue") to find the appropriate variant ID in the (hidden) master list.

To initialize Shopify's OptionSelectors, try adding this script tag immediately after your form to see if it helps:

```
{% if product.variants.size > 1 %}
<script>
function selectCallback(variant, selector){
  // This is where you would put any code that you want to run when the variant changes.
}

var variantIdFieldIdentifier = 'variant-select';
new Shopify.OptionSelectors(variantIdFieldIdentifier, { 
  product: {{ product | json }},     // Product object required to know how options map to variants
  onVariantSelected: selectCallback, // Function to do any interesting stuff (eg: update price field, image, etc) when selections change
  enableHistoryState: true           // When true, will update the URL to be a direct link to the currently-selected variant
})
</script>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Ah it's adding to cart, but It's looking like the following https://imgur.com/LWK40ip

Comment: Hmm. I thought that the original ID field was automatically hidden by the OptionSelectors code.  If not, you may need to do that manually.  It also looks like you're using a product that only has the single (default) variant, so you may also want to add some code to your form to account for that.  Adding in a few small edits...

Comment: How would I go about hiding the select box all together if there isn't more than 1 variant?

Comment: If you want the main ID to always be hidden, just set a CSS style somewhere (either inline or in your main CSS sheet) to make it display:none.  Alternatively, you could change it from a select box to a hidden input. Example: `<input type="hidden" id="variant-select" name="id" value="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id }}" />`